# Objective-c creation of PublicKey

Tags: objective-c

will you (anyone) please let me know how will i create a publicKey using Modulus and exponent(only two values whatever we have).

in java this is so simple.

```
RSAPublicKeySpec spec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, publicExponent);
KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");                                                                               
PublicKey pub = factory.generatePublic(spec);
```

I want to know how it could be done in objective-c.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve the same using [ideawu RSA libraies](https://github.com/ideawu/Objective-C-RSA), I had some issues with the encoding of the public key as their libraries assume that you need the footer and headers in the key (i.e. BEGIN PUBLIC KEY and END PUBLIC KEY) and they don't url encode the result that I required, so I slightly modified one of their methods and it worked, perfectly:

```
+ (NSString *)encryptString:(NSString *)str publicKey:(NSString *)pubKey{

    NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:pubKey options:0];
    NSString *decodedKey = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decodedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    decodedKey = [decodedKey stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" withString:@""];
    decodedKey = [decodedKey stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-----END PUBLIC KEY-----" withString:@""];

    NSData *data = [RSA encryptData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] publicKey:decodedKey];
    NSString *ret = base64_encode_data(data);
    ret = [ret stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet]];
    return ret;
}
```

Besides that, the library was really easy to import and compiled without warnings or errors.